# filtering outside of the ng-repeat statement

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to filter items from an `ng-repeat` but in a smaller scope.

i.e. Instead of this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
<tbody ng-repeat="actors in Users | filter:search">
    <tr>
        // td's
    </tr>

    <tr>
       // td's
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Can I do this somehow?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
<tbody ng-repeat="actors in Users">
    <tr ng-filter="filter:search">
        // td's
    </tr>

    <tr>
       // td's
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I do not wish to filter by the second `tr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple table bodies inside a table, so you could do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
<tbody ng-repeat="actors in Users">
    <tr ng-filter="filter:search">
        // td's with {{actor.fieldx}}
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-repeat="actors in Users">
    <tr >
        // td's with {{actor.fieldy}}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Interesting. Will that cause double the run-time due to repeating twice?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. But that's the price for fancy stuff :)